# Remove reference to footnote number in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing

When creating my bibliography it adds a number behind the book which links to the number of the footnote like:

> Finkenzeller 2012
>
> Finkenzeller, Klaus: RFID-Handbuch. Hanser, Carl GmbH + Co., 2012 5

As you can see its the number 5. How can I remove this number?

At the moment im just using this for bib:

```
\bibliography{Bibliographie} 
\bibliographystyle{natdin}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: ill add an example next time. your answer was totally right :)

Answer (score 2):

You have enabled the option `backref` defined by the package `hyperref`. You have to deactivate this option by `backref=false`