# Citation in JabRef

Tags: biblatex

The following code is the BibTeX source:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{El-Hakim2003b,
  author = {El-Hakim, S.F. and Beraldin, J.-A. and Blais, F.},
  title = {Critical Factors and Configurations for Practical Image-Based 3D
    Modeling},
  booktitle = {6th Conference on 3D Measurement Techniques},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {II},
  pages = {159-167.},
  address = {Zurich,Switzerland},
  month = {Sept. 22-25},
  owner = {Sayyad},
  timestamp = {2014.08.04}
```

The output looks like:

> El-Hakim, S., Beraldin, J.-A., and Blais, F. (2003b). Critical factors and congurations
>   for practical image-based **3d modeling**. In 6th Conference on 3D Measurement Techniques,
>   volume II, pages 159{167., Zurich,Switzerland. **3**

How can I have **3D**? I don't want to have only **3**.

Comment: `title = {Critical Factors and Configurations for Practical Image-Based {3D} Modeling},`? (Note the extra pair of curly braces around `3D`) See also [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864)

Comment: You are probably missing a space between `Zurich` and `Switzerland`. Also the `.` in the page range seems quite suspicious.

Comment: @ moewe How can I avoid page number '3'.

Comment: That last 3, is that the page number of the PDF where the citation is? If so, you've activated `backref`s somehow.

Comment: I think our best guess is some kind of back referencing mechanism, as Torbjørn T. points out. Depending on what packages you use for your bibliography, you need to et rid of the  `backref` package, might have passed the option `backref` to `hyperref` or have a option `backref` elsewhere. A [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces your problem would greatly help us. In the meantime you can have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146652/35864).

Comment: Any news here? Did you have any `backref` artefacts?